# Segmentation fault on insertion of more than one elements in the linked list in a sorted order

Tags: c++, sorting, linked-list, segmentation-fault, singly-linked-list

I tried to do an insertion sort in a linked list. When only one element is inserted(i.e the first one),it executes well and fine but for multiple elements it gives segmentation fault. Can anyone tell me where the problem is?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node
{
    int data;
    node* next;
} *head = NULL;

node* createNode(int x)
{
    node *temp = new node;
    temp->data = x;
    temp->next = NULL;
    return temp;
}

void insertSort(int x)
{
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        node  *temp = createNode(x);
        head = temp;
        return;
    }

    node *temp = createNode(x);
    node *prev = NULL;
    node *curr = head;
    bool inserted = false;

    while(curr != NULL || !inserted)
    {
        if(temp->data < head->data)
        {
            temp->next = head;
            head = temp;
            inserted = true;
        }

        else
        {
        if(temp->data < curr->data)
            {
                prev->next = temp;
                temp->next = curr;
                inserted = true;
             }
            else
            {
                prev = curr;
                curr = curr->next;
            }
        }


    }

    if(!inserted)
    {
    prev->next = temp;
    }

}

void display()
{
    node *p = head;
    while(p != NULL)
    {
        cout<<p->data<<" ";
        p = p->next;
    }

}
```

Comment: Now seems like a very good time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). More specifically, learn how to use a debugger to step through code, line by line, to see what it actually does, while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: This is a great opportunity to learn to use your debugger.  If you run your program through a debugger it should tell you exactly where the segfault is happening, and you should be able to look at the values for all relevant variables and see what's wrong.  (You're probably dereferencing a null pointer somewhere, or a pointer pointing to garbage memory.)

Comment: When `curr` is nullptr, then `curr->data` will do bad things.

Comment: "more details" usually mean a [mre]. Where is `main`?

Comment: `||` means "or". Think about what happens when you reach the end of the list and haven't inserted anything.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude is totally right. I ran your code in a debugger, took me 2 minutes to find the error. It's a very trivial problem. And molbdnilo is wasting all the fun :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters the function `insertSort` has redundant code

```
if(head==NULL)
{
    node  *temp = createNode(x);
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    head = temp;
    return;
}
node *temp = createNode(x);
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Secondly the condition in the while statement

```
while(curr != NULL || !inserted)
```

is incorrect. There must be

```
while(curr != NULL && !inserted)
```

In any case the function is too complicated. It can be written simpler.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how the function can be implemented.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

struct node
{
    int data;
    node* next;
} *head = nullptr;

node* createNode(int x)
{
    return new node { x, nullptr };
}

std::ostream &  display( std::ostream &os = std::cout )
{
    for ( node *current = head; current != nullptr; current = current->next )
    {
        os << current->data << " - > ";
    }

    return os << "NULL";
}

void insertSort( int x )
{
    node *new_node = createNode( x );

    node **current = &head;

    while ( *current != NULL && not ( x < ( *current )->data ) ) 
    {
        current = &( *current )->next;
    }

    new_node->next = *current;
    *current = new_node;
}

int main() 
{
    const int N = 10;

    std::srand( ( unsigned int )std::time( nullptr ) );

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ ) insertSort( std::rand() % N );

    display() << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
1 - > 2 - > 2 - > 3 - > 3 - > 3 - > 3 - > 8 - > 9 - > 9 - > NULL
```